# Tablas distintas al modelo

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc, model

Tengo  un proyecto que lo estamos manejando por modelos en *back* y *front* (angular-spring).

Hice una consulta personalizada, para traerme los datos en el modelo, y los trae bien, pero si entro al formulario de captura al intentar guardarlos me dice que dichos campos no existen.

Tuve que crear los campos para la consulta personalizada), pero no funciona el *JsonIgnore* y el *Trancent*.

La consulta que hice fue:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = " " +
    " SELECT  " +
            " personas.per_id AS per_id, " +
            " personas.per_nombre AS per_nombre, " +
            " personas.per_rss AS per_rss, " +
            " personas.per_twitter AS per_twitter, " +
            " personas.per_facebook AS per_facebook, " +
            " personas.per_url AS per_url, " +
            " personas.per_status AS per_status, "+
            " personas.per_id_usr AS per_id_usr, " +
            " personas.per_id_sec AS per_id_sec, " +
            " (SELECT sum(fuentes.fnt_total_registros) FROM fuentes WHERE fuentes.per_id = personas.per_id) AS totalnoticia, " +
            " (SELECT MAX(fuentes.fnt_fecha_scrap) FROM fuentes WHERE fuentes.per_id = personas.per_id ) AS ultimaactualizacion, " +
            " personas.per_fecha_creacion AS per_fecha_creacion " +
    " FROM " +
        " personas " +
    " WHERE " +
        " personas.per_id_sec = :per_id_sec " +
    " GROUP BY per_id ")
List<Persona> getPersonaByIndiceSectorial(@Param("per_id_sec") Integer per_id_sec);
```

Mi modelo es :

```
@JsonIgnore
private String totalnoticia;
@JsonIgnore
public String getTotalnoticia() {
    return totalnoticia;
}

@JsonIgnore
private Date ultimaactualizacion;
@JsonIgnore
public Date getUltimaactualizacion() {
    return ultimaactualizacion;
}

public Persona(){
    super();
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)

Si lo pongo como *ignore* cuando listo los resultados me regresa los valores nulos del modelo, `totalnoticia` y `ultimaactualizacion`, pero sí, los dejo como modelo, tal y como está.

Al insertar datos me marca error porque dice que las columnas `totalregistros` y `ultimaactualizacion` no se encuentran en mi tabla de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen creo que ya pude arreglar lo de almacenar  los datos, ya no marca problemas con eso:

Lo solucione:

```
 @Column (name = "totalnoticia", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String totalnoticia;
```

Sin embargo al meterme al registro para editarlo me marca el error de que 
totalnoticia no existe en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se presenta al acceder al registro para editarlo e eliminarlo.

Comment: La columna totalnoticia, ¿se llama exactamente así en BD?

Answer (score 0):

Tanto totalnoticia como ultimaactualización son columnas generadas a traves de una query no son columnas propias de la tabla, para usar la etiqueta `@Column` debes hacer referencia a una columna de la tabla, si no tendrás que crear una vista en la base de datos y mapearla.